# Responsive bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Есть такая карусель http://jsfiddle.net/q4qpyL2k/, как можно сделать так, чтобы при `@media (max-width: 768)` item в ней не складывались вниз, расширяя карусель, а менялись на один итем на ширину карусели, как при стандартном виде?

Answer (score 1):

Может так?

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-inner.onebyone-carosel {
        max-height: 250px;
    }
}
```